# What is the conjugate prior of Multivariate Log Normal distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions

For the univariate log-normal distribution, when mean is known, the conjugate prior is gamma distribution. But how about the multivariate log-normal distribution ? What is the conjugate prior ? Multivariate Gamma distribution ? What is the posterior distribution ?

I cannot find any information related to this. Hope someone could help me on this. Thanks.

Comment: Where do these questions arise? And what is your version of a multivariate Gamma distribution?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The question comes from the fact that log-normal distribution and gamma distribution are conjugate. And now I am working on the log multivariate normal distribution, but I do not know the the conjugate prior of that. It seems something related to gamma or wishart distribution. But I cannot find anything related.